# FFmpeg Conversion Error

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFmpeg to convert videos to the .webm format. I have installed all the dependencies listed here: http://www.videochat-scripts.com/install-ffmpeg-mplayer-flvtool2-yamdi-x264-theora-mp3lame-vorbis-ogg-faac/

I am using the following expression:

```
ffmpeg -i[imput.avi] [output.webm]
```

But I get the following error:

```
Could not find input stream matching output stream #0.0
```

I have tested to make sure I have the correct codecs/formats installed:

```
$ ./ffmpeg -formats 2> /dev/null | grep WebM
 E webm            WebM file format

$ ./ffmpeg -codecs 2> /dev/null | grep libvpx
 DEV    libvpx          libvpx VP8
```

I hope someone can help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shouldn't it be:

```
ffmpeg -i imput.avi output.webm
```

?

you can try to help ffmpeg to match your streams by providing exact map, some info here: howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#map

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was trying to show [input] [output] as they are not the actual file names. Sorry for the confusion. I do have it in the 'ffmpeg -i imput.avi output.webm' format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I have figured it out. It was a problem with the installation. A couple of installs later, it has worked itself out. Thanks again!