# ffmpeg file conversion unreadable

Tags: ffmpeg

I used ffmpeg to shorten a Videohive file from 14 seconds to 5 seconds with the following entry on the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i 15_Shopping_VKV.mov -t 5 shoes.mp4
```

The file doesn't work when I try to play it with Quicktime. Along with other Google searches, I looked at the following links in Stackoverflow for suggestions:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831944/unreadable-files
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818681/ffmpeg-conversion-error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22307229/ffmpeg-mp4-file-is-not-valid
```

At this point I'm out of ideas to figure out what's wrong, let alone how to fix the problem.

Here are some additional details:

I managed to edit a few other Videohive files but each file comes in slightly different format and although I've converted a number of other files with a similar entry or one that adjusts the codec to something web ready, I've been unable to successfully convert this file.  Like all of the other original videohive files it is readily read by QuickTime.  Only after the conversion does this file not work.  All other files I've converted worked with the following conversions for example:

```
ffmpeg -i mainfile.mp4 -t 5:00 rave.mp4
```

OR

```
ffmpeg -i 00299.mov -c:v libx264 dating.mp4
```

Here are a few additional details that may help:

1) a link to the broken file

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/files.parsetfss.com/90b6030c-d712-42ec-b2ee-deb43a4dd277/tfss-79b45914-9ada-4c1c-8fbc-8d652f8c00c7-shoes.mp4
```

2) The printout of ffmpeg process

```
News-MacBook-Air:CP08.14.15 newuser$ ffmpeg -i 15_Shopping_VKV.mov  -t 5  shoes.mov
ffmpeg version 2.7.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.7.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-libfreetype --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libspeex --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopus --enable-frei0r --enable-libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=jpeg2000 --extra-cflags='-I/usr/local/Cellar/openjpeg/1.5.1_1/include/openjpeg-1.5 ' --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '15_Shopping_VKV.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2015-03-07 22:03:36
  Duration: 00:00:14.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 78240 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/bt709/bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 78231 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 30k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-07 22:03:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : Photo - JPEG
      timecode        : 00:02:36;02
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-07 22:15:55
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:02:36;02
File 'shoes.mov' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
No pixel format specified, yuvj422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] 264 - core 144 r2533 c8a773e - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mov, to 'shoes.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-03-07 22:03:36
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:02:36;02
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  150 fps=6.9 q=-1.0 Lsize=    3953kB time=00:00:04.93 bitrate=6557.7kbits/s    
video:3950kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.080847%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] frame I:1     Avg QP:25.46  size: 71679
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] frame P:72    Avg QP:25.36  size: 40886
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] frame B:77    Avg QP:27.53  size: 13357
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] consecutive B-frames:  0.7% 89.3% 10.0%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] mb I  I16..4: 16.5% 80.0%  3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] mb P  I16..4:  5.3% 14.6%  0.6%  P16..4: 41.1% 10.6%  3.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] mb B  I16..4:  0.4%  1.2%  0.0%  B16..8: 32.7%  4.0%  0.7%  direct: 2.8%  skip:58.2%  L0:36.3% L1:53.2% BI:10.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] 8x8 transform intra:71.7% inter:86.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 52.7% 78.6% 18.2% inter: 14.1% 26.4% 0.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] i16 v,h,dc,p: 26% 18%  5% 51%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 13% 20%  4%  8% 12%  6%  8%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 15% 12%  4% 14% 14%  7%  5%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] i8c dc,h,v,p: 45% 12% 27% 16%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] ref P L0: 65.2% 18.5% 11.3%  5.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] ref B L0: 90.7%  9.1%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] ref B L1: 99.1%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbc9400a000] kb/s:6463.90
```

Comment: Thanks LordNeckbeard! I will try Super User next time. I didn't know about that before now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

From your console output:

```
No pixel format specified, yuvj422p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
```

## Solution

Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as an output option to your command.

Comment: I take that comment back I tried yuvj422p but only yuv420p will work. Thank you sir!